# Prove that every linear map on a finite dimensional vector space is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

Need to know how to prove that every linear map is continuous.  working with finite dimensional vector spaces. It's one of the problems I'm currently working on as revision for an
upcoming test.

I know that that a map is continuous if the preimage of any open set is open but can't seem to figure out the full proof.

Comment: It's good that you can't figure out the proof, since the claim is not true.

Comment: Are you working with finite dimensional vector spaces?

Comment: @Sigur Yes i am. Chris, why do you claim that it's not true? Thanks

Comment: It's only false in infinite-dimensional vector spaces, Denis.

Comment: Thanks @KevinCarlson How would I go about solving it in finite dimensional vector spaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the proof for finite dimensional vector spaces:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuous_linear_map#If_a_linear_map_is_finite_dimensional.2C_the_linear_map_is_continuous

Comment: Appreciated! Can't believe I didn't find this all along. Thanks